# NoMethodError in Articles#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, show, nomethoderror

I was using the tutorial on Getting Started with Rails http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html

I've already finished the tutorial, and now i'm using what i've done to create a site for a school work, i just want to add the "data" file on db/migrate/20161005160810_create_articles.rb, but i`m getting this message error

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line #12 raised:
       undefined method `data' for #<Article:0x007f8bcab2cfe8>
        Extracted source (around line #12):

        <p>
          <strong>Data:</strong>
          <%= @article.data %>
        </p>
```

and my articles_controller is like this

```
        class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

      http_basic_authenticate_with name: "mateus", password: "mateus", except: [:index, :show]

      def index
        @articles = Article.all
      end

      def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @article = Article.new
      end

      def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      end

      def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
          redirect_to @article
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])

        if @article.update(article_params)
          redirect_to @article
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy

        redirect_to articles_path
      end


        def article_params
          params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :data)
        end

    end
```

Could someone help me?

Edit1: I used `rake db:migrate:status` then i got this:

```
mateusjs:~/workspace (master) $ rake db:migrate:status

database: app_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20161005160810  Create articles
   up     20161005185521  Create comments
   up     20170209222858  Parte2
```

Comment: I forgot to mencion than i'm using Cloud9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `schema.rb` show that your `Article` has a `data` attribute? 
A quick way to test this is to go into your console and

```
$ bundle exec rails console

> Article
```

And see if the `data` is there.

If not, you might need to do two things;

1. Make a migration which is to say go to the terminal and do something like;

`$ bundle exec rails g migration AddDataToArticle data:integer`

2. After you do that step you need to `bundle exec rails db:migrate`

Comment: I think that it works for me, i didn't had a `data` in my `schema.rb`. So i just did what you told me and it works. For now at least hehehe. Tks

Comment: @MateusJose great to hear! And, welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind helping out future SO'ers by marking my response as the one that answered your question. The _green checkmark_ helps out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a new migration doing like:

```
rails g migration AddDataToArticle data:binary

rails db:migrate
```

`data:binary` because I assume that the "file" itself should be stored.

Or did you change your already defined migration. As there is currently no `data` attribute present - ruby assumes that this should be a method.

Could you append your migrations to your question?

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of the issue and what you are trying to accomplish, you have forgotten to apply the migration to your database.

If you have **changed an existing migration**, you would need to re-apply it by running the following command (assuming you're running Rails 5.xx):

```
rails db:migrate:up VERSION=20161005160810
```

other Rails versions should accept this command:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20161005160810
```

If you have **created a new migration**, you still need to apply the migration. Here is what you would do in Rails 5.xx:

```
rails db:migrate
```

other Rails versions should accept this command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Hope this helps!